# Maximum number of edges in a concave polyhedron given n vertices

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra, planar-graphs

Given $n$ vertices of a concave polyhedron (3D), what are the maximum amount of edges it can have?

I know for convex polyhedra the upper bound is $3n-6$. Does this also hold for concave polyhedra?

Also, if $3n-6$ edges is also the upper bound for concave polyhedra, is this due to the fact that every concave polyhedron can be represented as a planar graph?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define *polyhedron*.
Do you allow "holes" like in a donut?
While I have no answer to the case of general $n$ (this might be very hard), here is a polyhedron on $n=7$ vertices with the maximal number of

$${7\choose 2}=21 \;\text{ edges},$$

which is bigger than $3n-6=15$.

It is called the [Császár polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cs%C3%A1sz%C3%A1r_polyhedron), and there is an edge between any two vertices:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $E \le 3V-6$ is an easy corollary of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Polyhedra) for polyhedra $$V-E+F=2,$$ where $V$ is the number of vertices, $E$ is the number of edges, and $F$ is the number of faces.  To prove the inequality, note that each face has at least three edges.  Counting edges on all faces, we have $2E \ge 3F$ and $F \le \frac{2}{3}E$. Replacing $F$ with $\frac{2}{3}E$ in the Euler's formula proves the desired inequality.

The Euler's formula above holds for any (possibly concave) polyhedron whose boundary is topologically equivalent to a sphere and whose faces are topologically equivalent to disks.  That condition prohibits [toroidal polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_polyhedron) and faces with “holes”.

For an arbitrary polyhedron of the [topological genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Topology) $g$ (assuming again that faces have no “holes”), the modified formula is $$V-E+F=2-2g.$$  Applying the same argument as above, we have $$E \le 3V+6(g-1).$$

As an example, the [Császár polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cs%C3%A1sz%C3%A1r_polyhedron) from M. Winter's answer has genus $g=1$ and $E=3V$.  Note that the genus $g$ may grow superlinearly in the number of vertices.  The article [“Polyhedral Surfaces of High Genus”](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412093) of Günter M. Ziegler constructs a sequence of polyhedra with $V=2^m$, $E=3m2^{m−2}$, and $F=m2^{m−1}$.  Those polyhedra have $E=\frac{3}{4} V \log V$, which grows superlinearly in $V$.